# DNS setup problems with Windows Azure VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, azure

What is the proper to setup the A record (or CNAME) for a Windows Azure VPS? I can't connect to my website after setting up IIS and believe I don't have the correct DNS setup.

- I created a small VPS instance with the default Windows Server 2012 configuration.
- I RDP'd in and added the Webserver role.
- In my DNSMadeEasy control panel I added an A record with my Public Virtual IP Address.
- In IIS I went to the default website and added bindings for the hostname of my website, so I should be able to type mywebsite.com and see the IIS 8 splash screen, but instead my browser cannot connect.
- I attempted to navigate to the site by typing in my Virtual IP address into the browser and still cannot connect.
- I RDP'd back into the machine and turned off Windows Firewall. No change, still cannot navigate to my website.
- From within IIS I double checked my binding. If I click "browse *:80" I can bring up my website in IE with the http:// localhost address. If I click "browse mywebsite on *.80" IE says "This page cannot be displayed.", from within the RDP session I can view the site if I navigate to http:// 127.0.0.1 but not if I navigate to my Virtual IP, nor can I view the page if I try navigating to http:// mywebservername.cloudapp.net

I'm thinking I must be fundamentally not understanding how do DNS setup with Azure VPS but my initial Google searches aren't turning up any helpful information.

(spaces added after the http:// so serverfault doesn't try and render them as valid urls.)

Answer (score 2):

I found out endpoints must now be configured for Azure VPS instances, adding one solved my problem. Thanks.

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/5f6ab966-2840-4b02-b665-9dfb6cf0bee5

Comment: I can't up the answer due to low points on here, but that helped me out perfectly! I just needed to go into the Azure portal and add an enpoint for port 80. Just click on the VPS and then click Enpoints section.